# Backup Postgres from Python on Win10

Tags: python, postgresql, shell, backup, os.system

I'm trying to backup Postgres from Python on Win10.

I'm working on Anaconda python 3.8, Win10 machine with Postgres12 local. On path environment variable I have postgres (lib and bin), no anaconda, and python 3.8 (no the anaconda one).

I'm able to correctly backup the database using on window's command shell:

```
pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/test > C:\backup\dumpfile3.dump
```

but when I run it on anaconda:

```
os.system("pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/test > C:\backup\dumpfile3.dump"  )
```

I get as output `1` , witch is error code. It creates the file, but it's empty.

Using:

```
import subprocess
stk= 'pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/test > C:\backup\dumpfile3.dump'

try:
    subprocess.check_output(stk, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

I get :

```
RuntimeError: command 'pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/test > C:\backup\dumpfile3.dump' return with error (code 1): b"'pg_dump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

If I use: `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.call` I doesn't produce error, but the created file it's empty.

It seems that neither `os.system` or `subprocess` on the anaconda interpreter, got access to the environment variables on the command shell. How is this possible? and how I can overcome it?. It is different user invoking the shell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Computer was restarted, and it solves the issue... . There was no change in the paths, I believe that from the moment things (python ,postgres, ...) were installed, the machine hasn"t been restarted.

```
import os
os.system("pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/test > C:\backup\dumpfile3.dump" )
```

worked!, and

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(r"C:\some\path\backup.bat")
```

also worked!. Inside backup.bat is:

```
pg_dump pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/test > C:\backup\dumpfile3.dump
```

I imagine that the issue was that the anaconda interpreter need a system restart to get access to the environment variables (where the postgres variable was), witch make very little sense as `return with error (code 1): b"'pg_dump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"` seen like a console message.

If anyone have a better explanation, is welcome.